# static library on Windows platform issue

Tags: static

Two questions about static library on Windows platform,

1. How to check whether a lib is a static library (or not, e.g. import library for a DLL or some other format which is not a legal static library file even if file name has .lib extension);
2. How to check whether MT or MD flag is used when build a static library?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 1):

Your question 2 is easy. the `dumpbin` tool in VC can simply do this:

```
dumpbin /directives your_static_lib.lib
```

And then check the dependency library names by [MSVC runtime library list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.71).aspx)