# Force linking against Python release library in debug mode in Windows/Visual Studio from CMake

Tags: python, cmake, visual-studio-2017, boost-python

I'm developing a Python binding for a C++ library using Boost Python, for Linux and Windows (Visual Studio).

In Windows, the static Boost Python library has a dependency against Python (this is motive for another thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797584/why-does-static-version-of-the-boost-python-library-has-a-dependency-to-python-i)), so, in my CMake config I need to do:

```
if((${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux") OR APPLE)
     target_link_libraries(my_python_module ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
elseif(WIN32 AND MSVC)
    add_definitions(/DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB)
    target_link_libraries(my_python_module ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) #This includes the Boost Python library
    # Even though Boost Python library is included statically, in Windows it has a dependency to the Python library.
    target_link_libraries(my_python_module ${Python_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

This works fine in Linux, but in Windows, it only works in Release mode, not in Debug, in which case I always get a:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: Can't open file 'python37.lib'`

After some hair pulling I noticed the issue was caused by CMake instructing Visual Studio to link against **`'python37_d.lib'`** instead of **`'python37.lib'`** in the Debug mode.

However, as I described in the [linked issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797584/why-does-static-version-of-the-boost-python-library-has-a-dependency-to-python-i), the [officially provided](https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.70.0/binaries/boost_1_70_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe) Boost Python **debug** library is linked against the Python **release** library, not the debug one. So, the solution would be to force the link against the Python release library, regardless of the build type. Unfortunately, **`${Python_LIBRARIES}`** sets the library automatically depending on the mode, and I wouldn't like to explicitly specify python37.lib in my code (since I can upgrade Python and I don't want to have to change my CMake scripts because of that).

I found some similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497348/debug-and-release-library-linking-with-cmake-visual-studio/5497425) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209929/linking-different-libraries-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-cmake-on-windows), but that doesn't reflect the exact situation I'm facing. Based on those, I tried setting:

`target_link_libraries(my_python_module optimized ${Python_LIBRARIES})`

But that didn't work either. So, the question is:

Is there a way to force the usage of the Python release library in Debug mode *WITHOUT* having to set it explicitly and leaving the Python CMake package to do it automatically instead. By explicit I mean doing:

`target_link_libraries(my_python_module python37)`

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this. You could build a debug version of Python to use with a debug version of the module. The problem is that the interpreter and any code linked into it all need to be using with the same C/C++ runtime library (there are both debug and release of of it).

Comment: According to `FindBoost.cmake` [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L141), you can set a variable `Boost_USE_DEBUG_PYTHON` before calling `find_package(Boost ...)`. Try setting that variable to `OFF` `set(Boost_USE_DEBUG_PYTHON OFF)`. Does that help?

Comment: @martineau, I think you misunderstood my question. I already have the Boost precompiled libraries, and the Boost.Python debug one was indeed compiled linking against the Python release library (`python37.lib`), not the debug one (`python37_d.lib`). But, since `FindPython.cmake` automatically sets the proper Python library for each build type, my code is trying to link against `python37_d.lib` in debug mode, when I have to do it against `python37.lib`. In fact, forcing the linkage against `python37.lib` in debug fixes the issue, but that implies changing my CMake config and I'd prefer not.

Comment: @kanstar, unfortunately not, `Boost_USE_DEBUG_PYTHON` didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @A.Palma Sorry, I misunderstood your question. With my suggestion, you will only get the release version of `libboost_python` and not `libpython`. Did you have a look at `FindPython.cmake`? The variable `Python_FIND_ABI` looks interesting (see [here](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindPython.cmake#L140)). Try `set(Python_FIND_ABI "OFF" "ANY" "ANY")` (will set debug to `OFF` and malloc and unicode to `ANY`) before doing `find_package(Python)`.

Comment: Of course, that would be too easy: Python ships with pyconfig set to use pragmas to inject a pythonx_d.lib dependency: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/PC/pyconfig.h#L270-L276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `set(Python_FIND_ABI "OFF" "ANY" "ANY")` as suggested in the comments by kanstar would be the correct way to do this. However, while `Python_FIND_ABI` is in CMake [master](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake), it hasn't been released yet in the [latest version](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.15.2/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake) (v3.15.2 as of this writing).

In the meantime, there are solutions dependent on the CMake version.

**CMake 3.12 and above**

It's possible to link against [FindPython](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.13.0/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake)'s `Python_LIBRARY_RELEASE`, which isn't meant to be part of the module's [public interface](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/FindPython.html), but the variable is set correctly nonetheless.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)
find_package(Python ..<choose your COMPONENTS; refer to FindPython docs>..)
if(WIN32 AND MSVC)
  target_link_libraries(my_python_module ${Python_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
endif()
```

**CMake 3.0.4 to 3.11**

Thanks to a comment by @Phil, we can expand the answer to include earlier CMake versions which had the [FindPythonLibs](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/v3.4.0/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake) module that sets the `PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE` variable instead.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
find_package(PythonLibs ..<refer to FindPythonLibs docs>..)
if(WIN32 AND MSVC)
  target_link_libraries(my_python_module ${PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
endif()
```

Comment: I believe that should be ``${PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE}`` in all caps.

Comment: @Phil Is there a case where `Python_LIBRARY_RELEASE` doesn't work? `Python_*`, `Python2_*`, and `Python3_*` are the prefixes to use according to [FindPython docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html).

Comment: @Phil Ah, I think you might be referring to [FindPythonLibs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPythonLibs.html), which does have the token `PYTHON_LIBRARY_RELEASE` ([source](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/release/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake)), but the entire module's deprecated since 3.12.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. This is what the pybind11 example uses, and I am blindly following that. Thanks for your help and the excellent answer!

Comment: what about visual studio?

Comment: @Nickpick assuming for example Python 3.7; in Visual Studio go to <your project> -> Properties -> (top left) set Configuration: Debug. Then in Linker -> Input, make sure the Additional Dependencies field has `python37.lib` and not `python37_d.lib`

Comment: @Konafa, yes, but that won't be reflected in CMakeList, but would only work if used with visual studio solution file

Comment: The original answer already covers cmake. I probably misunderstood your question then; help me understand what you mean.

Comment: Windows 10, VS2019, Python 3.10: this doesn't work, with Py310 installed into C:\Python310:

```
LIST(INSERT CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 0 "C:\\Python310")
SET(Python_USE_SHARED_LIBS  OFF)
SET(Python_IMPLEMENTATIONS CPython)
SET(Python_FIND_ABI "OFF" "ANY" "ANY")
FIND_PACKAGE(Python3 3.10.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development.embed)
```
fails to find python in debug build, 
```